# Google analytics click events with jQuery

Tags: google-analytics

I have a long list of click events I need to track such as:

```
  ga('send', 'event', 'Global', 'Social Action', 'Twitter');
```

I am following the format of:

```
 $('#button').on('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
});
```

Is there a way to do this so I don't have to have multiple click events? So, instead of having #button, I can pass in the element somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Use a class instead of an id, and then add the class to every anchor tag you want to track.

For example, lets say you want to track the navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='home.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='books.html'>Books</a></li>
    <li><a href='magazines.html'>Magazines</a></li>
</ul>
```

After you add the HTML class to every anchor tag:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="gaTrack" href='home.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="gaTrack" href='books.html'>Books</a></li>
    <li><a class="gaTrack" href='magazines.html'>Magazines</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then use jQuery to select the class, and use .text() to grab the text within the anchor tag.

```
 $('.gaTrack').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', name);
});
```